# Is there a way to configure shovel programatically?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

we are developing a Spring-AMQP - RabbitMQ app. We want to use shovel to replicate the messages from a local queue to a remote queue but we want to make almost all the configuration of the messaging service from the spring app.

At this point we are able to create the queues, exchanges etc, etc. from the app itself but we can't find a way to configure shovel from the same app. Is there a way to achive this?

If we use federation plugin instead of shovel, is there a better way of configuring it rather than shovel using Spring-AMQP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's no way to configure shovel programmatically. What I did in the end was modifing directly the shovel configuration file from my application an later restart rabbitmq. Is an ugly solution but works.